# kivy python 3.x loop add widgets .kv

Tags: python, kivy

I have a python script like such:

```
class GuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #for i in range(24):
            #Grid.add_widget(Button(text='Test'))
        return Gui()

class Gui(BoxLayout):
    pass
```

And I have a .kv file like such:

```
<Gui>:
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
      text: 'Top'
    GridLayout:
      id: Grid
      cols: 5
      rows: 5
```

How do I apply a loop to add the 24 buttons to the GridLayout?

I thought that I could call the id Grid like shown in the python comments, but that fails.

How do I go about applying a loop to add buttons to the GridLayout in the kv file with the id Grid?

Answer (score 5):

I seemed to have figured out how to do the loop propery:

py

```
class GuiApp(App):

    def build(self)
        g = Gui()
        for i in range(24):
            g.grid.add_widget(Button(text='test'))
        return g

class Gui(BoxLayout):
    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
```

kv

```
<Gui>:
  grid: Grid
  BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
      text: 'Top'
    GridLayout:
      id: Grid
      cols: 5
  rows: 5
```

In order for it to work I needed to reference it _grid: Grid in the .kv file to be found by the ObjectProperty, the grid, when used in python needed to be lowercase

Comment: Nice one, just what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi, a bit late to the  party. Here you have used it for the main app. What if I am using screen managers and I have one of the screens in which I need to use the for loop using a kv file.

Comment: @UditHariVashisht I have to write another py script to generate the #screen kv# file...

Answer (score 2):

```
def build(self):
    layout = GridLayout()
    for i in range(24): layout.add_widget(...)
    return layout
```

I think at least

```
class GuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        g = Gui()
        for i in range(24):
            g.Grid.add_widget(Button(text='Test'))
        return g

class Gui(BoxLayout):
    Grid = ObjectProperty(None)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say more?

Comment: While this would work on its own, I need to add these widgets to the existing child widget BoxLayout>GridLayout in the .kv file

Comment: ok maybe my new solution will work ... not sure ... dont have kivy installed at the moment

Comment: on the second version, I am getting AttributError: 'NoneType' object has no attribue 'add_widget'. This is happening on the g.Grid.add_widget. I have gotten this before when trying to use the ObjectProperty

Comment: you have to tell it ... I forget how ... but its something like that ... maybe just `Grid = ObjectProperty(GridLayout())` ... dang i hate that .kv language its so much better to build your widgets with python :P